# lua socket receive reports same data multiple times

Tags: sockets, lua, luasocket

I have the following code which sits inside a loop (Simplified). `cscc` is a client socket connecting to a server on localhost. My server sends a single character to the client. However, I don't seem to be receiving it properly. Protocol is TCP.

```
    rect, _, st = socket.select({cscc}, nil, .5)

    if(rect[cscc] ~= nil) then
        data, err, part = csc:receive(512)
        if(part ~= nil) then
            print(err.." : "..part)
        end
        socket.sleep(1)
    end
```

When the character is sent from the server, I get the following line repeating as output:

`timeout :`

obviously, part is not null here. What is going on here? Why am I receiving the same thing over and over?

Comment: Maybe you're receiving a non-printable character (or `0` at the beginning)? Have you tested size of part? Perhaps the string is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the server never got to really send any data at all. Check if `part` is non empty and see what happens if you don't pass the third parameter to `socket.select`.

Answer (score 0):

The LuaSocket reference documentation says:

> *"In case of error, the method returns `nil` followed by an error message which can be the string 'closed' [...] or the string 'timeout' in case there was a timeout during the operation. Also, after the error message, the function returns the partial result of the transmission."*

The empty string would count as a 'partial result'.

---

Try testing against `(part and #part > 0)`, which will check that part is non-`nil`, then check if it actually contains any bytes.

It also might be worthwhile checking with `netcat` or similar to make sure that your server is actually sending the data you expect.